# Minimum Android API level for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, mobile-analytics

I am developing an Android application in which I am planning to integrate Google Analytics. Currently, my application's minimum API level is 10.

I have following questions:

1. What is the minimum API level required for Google Analytics?
2. What are the best alternatives of GA which supports API level 10?

Thank you.

Comment: What is preventing you from trying GA on an API 10 device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *API* limit to Google Analytics. According to official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), it appears that all devices that has *Google Play services* integrated in them **will** support Google Analytics integration to your app. It is also said in the official documentation that

> Google Analytics can be used and will work on devices that do not have Google Play Services. In this case you still download and use the Google Play Services SDK and Google Analytics will automatically fall back to local dispatching.

So, it can be used by *downloading* the Google Play Services SDK, least bother about the *API Level*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google Analytics Website: https://developers.google.com/analytics/
There does not appear to be an API limit for Google Analytics.
For alternatives there seems to be a handful ranging from Piwik and Gauges.
You can find more information here: http://alternativeto.net/software/google-analytics/?platform=android

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.